# SAPI access from WCF app

Tags: .net, wcf, sapi

is it possible to access SAPI from a WCF app ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to access it from a WCF service?

I don't know for certain, but I suspect you'd need to make the service run as a single instance. If I recall correctly, SAPI was designed for use from a desktop application, and might depend on the existence of a message pump. You might have to host your service in a Windows Forms application in order to give it one.